# Socket.IO Library Obj-C error

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I started implementing Sockets with Socket.IO in my apps and web applications, I tried using different libraries for iOS (`socket.IO-objc` & `RocketIO`) but they both display an error when I try to run it.
Maybe someone can help me :)

an image [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoah3.png]

Thank you so much
Anton

Comment: From the image, it looks like you didn't add the proper source file to the compile sources in your target. I would [add an exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) then investigate where the dubugger stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `libicucore.dylib` to your project.
That was a issue on [SocketRocket github](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/issues/128) (that I suspect to be on se same basis that the ones you're using).